# asp.net mvc htmlencode trim after :

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am encoding in my controller when saving record. The thing is that when i enter this record abcccc:abcccc , the thing after : will be trimmed. it is working fine with other characters but : it is trimming after that . what might be the problem? The records are saved after doing Server.htmlencode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server.HtmlEncode("abcccc:abcccc")** returns **"abcccc:abcccc"** as there is nothing to encode.

I suspect the problem is somewhere else. Have you tried debugging the code?

PS. Why are you Html encoding data in the database in the first place?